# Determine whether the series converges or not.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Use the Comparsion Test or Limit Comparsion Test to determine whether the series converges or not.

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{n+\sqrt n}{n+n^2}$$

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1+3^n}{1+2^n}$$

thanks a lot

Comment: Show what you did first.

Comment: Check my editing your series is correct, and **please**" next time please do read first in our site's FAQ how to correctly write mathematics here, and *check* that what you wrote makes sense before you post it.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that @DonAntonio’s edit is correct, but you didn’t use enough parentheses to make your expressions unambiguous, and you had a couple of equals signs that made no sense, so do please check.

Answer (score 4):

Hints (pretty big, though, and assuming my editing the question is correct):

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{n+\sqrt n}{n+n^2}\geq \frac{n}{n^2+n^2}$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{1+3^n}{1+2^n}\geq \frac{ 3^n}{2\cdot 2^n} $$

Comment: Of course, that'll make it.

Answer (score 1):

The way @DonAntonio did above completes the proof. I just add another small approach to the second series. I use the ratio test for it so I am looking for the following limit when $n\to\infty$: $$\lim\bigg|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\bigg|$$ where in $a_n=\frac{1+3^n}{1+2^n}$. So I have: $$\lim\bigg|\frac{\frac{1+3^{n+1}}{1+2^{n+1}}}{\frac{1+3^n}{1+2^n}}\bigg|=\lim\bigg|0.5\bigg(\frac{1}{1+2^{n+1}}+1\bigg)\bigg(\frac{3}{\frac{2}{1+3^{n+1}}+1}\bigg)\bigg|=\frac{3}{2}>1$$ when $n$ tends to infinity. Therefore the second one is divergent.

Comment: Nice addition! $\quad +1\quad \ddot\smile \quad \checkmark!\;$